# Pressing ctrl J messes up hair

Tags: modeling, particles

I've been using Blender for about a year now.

I want the teeth to join with the head.
After pressing <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> the hair sticks out in every direction and the teeth still aren't connected with the head.

Both versions I downloaded had bugs in them, which gives me a really hard time to model my characters. The program is really slow.

Comment: A) Ask one question at a time, 1) Are they both selected, 2) To many polys or too much hair, 3) Scaling to zero makes it no size.

Comment: Welcome to the site :) Please try to keep to one question per post, this helps keep things organized and focused. Feel free to make as many posts as you like :)